# move object and it's children out of camera in unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a gameobject together with some children gameobject to represent the information to show up when specific circumstances occurred.

I have already ajusted the position of the information gameobject(together with its' children) in the cameraarea. The thing is that I want to move the gameobject(together with its' children) out of the camera, maybe on top or maybe on left. Following is the scratch to demonstrate the position I want to put it:

[image]

So that I could move the information gameobject and its' children (Red box) with some movement effect when needed, I have no problem with moving it back but could find an elegant way to move it out of the camera when the game started.

Mostly because I don't know how to calculate the position out of the camera.
Maybe find the upper border of the camera and the size of the gameobject and its children?

I know I could do this by maybe add a marker gameobject to represent the downer border of the information gameobject, and move it until it's not visible, but is there a more elegant way?

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your gameObject a child of a canvas?

Comment: @itay_421 nope, I found canvas is tricky in tweaking the size so I just use normal gameobject

Comment: Im working on a code for you.

Answer (score 0):

For this one, I would use the following trick: use any method (animation, coroutine, Update method...) to move your item out of screen the way you desire. Then you can use the [OnBecameInvisible](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameInvisible.html) event which is called when the item does not need to be rendered on any camera anymore. The event will there be used to detect that the parent object moved out of screen, and that you want to stop the current movement. You then just need to define in this event that you want to stop the current moving behavior, and you will be done.

```
void OnBecameInvisible() {
    // Stop moving coroutine, moving in Update or current animation.
}
```

There are probably more elegant ways of doing it as you said, but I think this method should be enough for what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It took me time, but I found this way for you, attach this script to your gameObject:

```
public Renderer rend;
//drag the camera to the script in the inspector
public Camera camera1;
Vector3 bottomleft;
Vector3 topright;

void Start()
{
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    //the top-right point of the camera bounds
    topright= camera1.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, transform.position.z));
    //the bottom-left point of the camera bounds
    bottomleft = camera1.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, transform.position.z));

    StartCoroutine(MoveUp());

}
IEnumerator MoveUp()
{
    //while the position and the height are lower that the Y of top right
    while (transform.position.y + rend.bounds.size.y < topright.y)
    {
        //move the object to the new position (move it up)
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + .01f, transform.position.z);
        //and wait for 1/100 of a second 
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(.001f);
    }
}
```

you can play with the WaitForSecondsRealtime value to change the velocity of moving.